# Generic type constraint syntax conflicts with inheritance syntax

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax

I want to constraint a template type to specific subclass, which is done like this:

```
// This class contains generic list template
// but specific implementation can be used
class MyClass<T> where T: IEnumerable {}
```

But I also want to implement a class, without template, that's:

```
class MyClass: MyClassBase {}
```

But how do I combine those two things? This is an error:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: IEnumerable : MyClassBase {}
```

Also error:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: IEnumerable, : MyClassBase {}
```

Error:

```
class MyClass<T> (where T: IEnumerable) : MyClassBase {}
```

Error:

```
class MyClass<T where T: IEnumerable>: MyClassBase {}
```

What's the correct syntax? [MSDN doesn't bother](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause) explaining it.

Comment: While the `where` constraint keyword doesn't "bother" explaining it, you looked at the wrong `where` documentation, here's the right one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint - note that this doesn't "bother" explaining this either but if you wanted to learn more about generic type constraints, this would be the page to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is to specify inheritance first, and then add `where`:

```
class MyClass<T> : MyClassBase where T: IEnumerable {
}
```

Here is the [corresponding C# grammar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2010/04/19/vb-and-c-grammar-for-vs2010/) specifying that `class_base` comes ahead of `type_parameter_constraints_clauses`:

> ```
> class_declaration ::= attributes? class_modifiers? partial? class
>     identifier type_parameter_list?
>     class_base?
>     type_parameter_constraints_clauses? class_body ;?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class BaseClass    { }

private class MyClass<T> : BaseClass
     where T : IEnumerable
{

}
```